# Can't figure out this SQL from a survey

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

There must be a simpler way to do this, but I'm very new at SQL. I got this data from a large survey and I need help with this. I want to find the average and total hours of homework from each class, but the data is formatted to where all grades are in one table. It shouldn't be that hard, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```
SELECT
  What_grade_are_you_in as Grade,
  How_much_free_time_do_you_have_each_night as FreeTime,
  AvgEnglish9HW,
  AvgBible9HW,
  AvgGov9HW,
  AvgMath9HW,
  AvgScience9HW,
  AvgLang9HW,
  AvgArt9HW,

  AvgEnglish10HW,
  AvgBible10HW,
  AvgGov10HW,
  AvgMath10HW,
  AvgScience10HW,
  AvgLang10HW,
  AvgArt10HW,

  AvgEnglish11HW,
  AvgBible11HW,
  AvgGov11HW,
  AvgMath11HW,
  AvgScience11HW,
  AvgLang11HW,
  AvgArt11HW,

  AvgEnglish12HW,
  AvgBible12HW,
  AvgGov12HW,
  AvgMath12HW,
  AvgScience12HW,
  AvgLang12HW,
  AvgArt12HW,

  SUM(AvgEnglish12HW, AvgBible12HW, AvgGov12HW, AvgMath12HW, AvgScience12HW, AvgLang12HW, AvgArt12HW) as TotalHW12,
  SUM(AvgEnglish11HW,AvgBible11HW,AvgGov11HW,AvgMath11HW,AvgScience11HW,AvgLang11HW,AvgArt11HW) as TotalHW11,
  SUM(AvgEnglish10HW,AvgBible10HW,AvgGov10HW,AvgMath10HW,AvgScience10HW,AvgLang10HW,AvgArt10HW) as TotalHW10,
  SUM(AvgEnglish9HW,AvgBible9HW,AvgGov9HW,AvgMath9HW,AvgScience9HW,AvgLang9HW,AvgArt9HW) as TotalHW9
FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` ,(
SELECT
AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_English) as AvgEnglish9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Bible) as AvgBible9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Gov) as AvgGov9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Math) as AvgMath9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Science) as AvgScience9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Foreign_Language) as AvgLang9HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Fine_Arts) as AvgArt9HW
FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` 
WHERE What_grade_are_you_in = 9 

SELECT
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_English) as AvgEnglish10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Bible) as AvgBible10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Gov) as AvgGov10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Math) as AvgMath10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Science) as AvgScience10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Foreign_Language) as AvgLang10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Fine_Arts) as AvgArt10HW
FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` 
WHERE What_grade_are_you_in = 10 

SELECT
AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_English) as AvgEnglish11HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Bible) as AvgBible11HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Gov) as AvgGov11HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Math) as AvgMath10HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Science) as AvgScience11HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Foreign_Language) as AvgLang11HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Fine_Arts) as AvgArt11HW
FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` 
WHERE What_grade_are_you_in = 11

SELECT
AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_English) as AvgEnglish12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Bible) as AvgBible12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Gov) as AvgGov12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Math) as AvgMath12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Science) as AvgScience12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Foreign_Language) as AvgLang12HW,
  AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Fine_Arts) as AvgArt12HW
FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` 
WHERE What_grade_are_you_in = 12
)  

GROUP BY
Grade
ORDER BY
TotalHW12,TotalHW11,TotalHW10,TotalHW9 DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: your output (in outer SELECT statement of example in your question) makes no sense at all! From one side it is grouped by grade, but from another side you have all grades in the same row! makes no sense at all!  So I went ahead and assumed below output is what is expected

It is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Grade,
  AvgEnglish,
  AvgBible,
  AvgGov,
  AvgMath,
  AvgScience,
  AvgLang,
  AvgArt,
  AvgEnglish + AvgBible + AvgGov + AvgMath + AvgScience + AvgLang + AvgArt AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT
    What_grade_are_you_in AS Grade
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_English) AS AvgEnglish,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Bible) AS AvgBible,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Gov) AS AvgGov,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Math) AS AvgMath,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Science) AS AvgScience,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Foreign_Language) AS AvgLang,
    AVG(On_average_how_much_homework_do_you_have_per_class_from_Fine_Arts) AS AvgArt
  FROM `omnihealth-1.HWLoad.HWLoad` 
  WHERE What_grade_are_you_in IN (9, 10, 11, 12)
  GROUP BY 1
)  
ORDER BY Total DESC
```